# A model's collection turns out to be a non-object

Tags: magento

I am trying to get a list of viewed products in Magento, but the following code:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => 1));
```

created the error message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

Why is the collection returned in getCollection() a non-object?

Comment: FYI: If the object returned wasn't a collection, you're get an error something like "Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter on a non-object".  Your exception is happening because something deeper in the filter/collection code is running into a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your filter call. Actually there is no store_id attribute for product  and in your case collection tries to get this attribute, but since it doesn't exist an error occurs. In report collection there is a special method created to specify store filter, so you code should look like this (also I included construction for proper type hinting):

```
/* @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Viewed_Collection */ // This enabled type hinting
$collection = Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')->getCollection();
$collection->setStoreId($storeId); // Setting data scope (e.g translated names, prices, etc)
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId); // Set filter by exact availability on this store.
```

Have fun with Magento development!

Comment: I'm confused. I'm looking at the report_viewed_product_index table, which does have store_id (as well as visitor_id and customer_id columns). How would I filter according to all these columns?

Comment: It filters by store association of the product (catalog_category_product_index)